# Ajax from submit is not working in codeigntier with out page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

guys, I am trying to submit my form using ajax but I don't know exactly what happened it's not posting the values to my table in the database, This is the first time I am using ajax for form submit can anyone help me what mistake I have done.

Here is my  view code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/theme1/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript"> -->
    <script type = "text/javascript">

        // Ajax post
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var organisation_name = $("input#organisation_name").val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Organisation/createOrg",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { organisation_name: organisation_name },
                    success: function(res) {
                        if (res) {
                            // Show Entered Value
                            jQuery("div#result").show();
                            jQuery("div#value").html(res.organisation_name);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="modal fade" id="createGroup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createGroup" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
                <form action="" id="user-groups-create" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create a New Organisation</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="group_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">New Organisation Name : </label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" id="organisation_name" name="organisation_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Organisation Name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" id="submit">Create Organisation</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my controller's method createOrg:

```
public function createOrg() {
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
    //Validating Name Field
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('organisation_name', 'organisation_name', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[15]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Organisation name need to be more than 3 characters and less than 15.');
        redirect('Organisation', $error);
    } else {
        //Setting values for tabel columns
        $data = array(
            'organisation_name' => $this->input->post('organisation_name')
        );
        //Transfering data to Model
        $this->Org_model->orgInsert($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Organisation created.');
        //Loading View
        redirect('Organisation');
    }
}
```

Here is my Model's method orgInsert:

```
function orgInsert($data) {
    // Inserting in Table(organisation)
    $this->db->insert('organisation', $data);
}
```

Can anyone help me what mistake I have done and I have checked my code properly I didn't find exactly where I have done a mistake and I want my modal popup should be there after submitting it until a user clicks on the close button. when I try to keep alert after  `jQuery.ajax({` it is not coming alert.. and I can able to get the value from `var organisation_name` in alert...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you have taken button type as `submit` your form will be posted normal way. use button type as `button`

Comment: i have changed but still when i click on submit button it is not working at all..i mean it is not clickable

Comment: i have edited my question can u please check once

Comment: see your console what error it shows pls check

Comment: there is no erros from console side

Comment: can you please help me where i have done mistake

Comment: @pradeep why you have deleted your answer?it is working right  what happened

Comment: @user200 may be because it may not help you much

Comment: @pradeep hi praddep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will work you :**

```
$('#user-groups-create').on('submit',function(e){
    var organisation_name = $("#organisation_name").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?=site_url('Organisation/createOrg');?>",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {'organisation_name': organisation_name},
      success: function(res) {
        if (res)
        {
          alert(res);
          window.location.href = "<?=site_url('Organisation');?>";
          $("div#result").show();
          $("div#value").html(res.organisation_name);
        }
      },
    });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Your controller's method `createOrg` should be like this :

```
public function createOrg() 
{
    $data = array(
        'organisation_name' => $this->input->post('organisation_name')
    );
    //Transfering data to Model
    $this->Org_model->orgInsert($data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Organisation created.');
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not storing in my table

Comment: the insert part is same , not changed anything, make sure you have `organisation_name` in your method

Comment: i have taken your code as it is and i didn't change anything from model.but still values are not storing in table

Comment: see your console for the errors and make sure you have button type submit

Comment: yes my button type is submit and i couldnt able to see any errors in console

Comment: can u show me screen shot of your console after click button

Comment: my pleasure, happy coding

Comment: reload your page after successful of ajax in success method see my answer in success method

Comment: u can redirect with ajax after success not before that otherwise u will not get your data in success method as u have done in your question , u can redirect in ajax's success, its a proper way to  do it

Comment: hi can you please give me solution with out page refresh i want to show the view page dat a

Comment: okay i am trying to update the values using modal popup when i click on edit button..i will post and give you the link here in half hour is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Working by changing the script to like this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
// Ajax post
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('form').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var organisation_name = $("input#organisation_name").val();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Organisation/createOrg",
dataType: "html",
data: {organisation_name: organisation_name},
success: function(data) {
alert('success');
}
});
});
});

</script>
```